# Comparing elements of different types of Arrays in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, compare, array-filter

**I want to compare `fileName` and `title` and pass the different ones to another variable.**

**I want to compare `fileName` and `title` and delete the same values from `allQuiz` array.**

**What I want is this; Let me return the different ones as array type.**

`downloadedQuiz` and `allQuiz` have the same array type. However, I want to compare two different variable values of different array type.

```
self.unDownloadedQuiz = self.downloadedQuiz.difference(from: self.allQuiz)
```

**I want to compare fileName and title values.**

*I was using this code before, but this code works on variables with the same type array.*

```
self.unDownloadedQuiz = self.downloadedQuiz.difference(from: self.allQuiz)

extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    func difference(from other: [Element]) -> [Element] {
        let thisSet = Set(self)
        let otherSet = Set(other)
        return Array(thisSet.symmetricDifference(otherSet))
    }
}
```

**Values:**

```
var myFile: [MyFile]
ver allQuiz: [Quiz]
```

**MyFile Model:**

```
struct MyFile {
   
    var fileName: String 
      ....
}
```

**Quiz Model:**

```
struct Quiz: Codable, Realmable, Hashable {
    
    var title: String = ""
      ....  
}
```

Comment: Do you expect to get a `[String]` as the output?

Comment: Yes sir. I edited my question

Comment: Can you show some sample inputs and outputs to illustrate what you want? The code you added in your edit doesn't make much sense at all, especially the `$0.fileName != self.allQuiz.map({$0.title})` part, which is always true - one file name is never equal to an _array_ of quiz titles.

Comment: @Sweeper I edited my question again sir.

Comment: That is not what I asked for, but I see that you edited your first comment. So you _do_ want a `[String]` now?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the array extension you provided, it looks like you want this, which is an array of the `fileName` properties of the files compared with an array of the `title` properties of the quizzes:

```
let files: [MyFile] = //...
let quizzes: [Quiz] = //...
let result : [String] = files.map(\.fileName).difference(from: quizzes.map(\.title))
```

Comment: You updated your question after I wrote this and now the file stuff seems to be different so I'm not sure it applies. Let me know.